# Select 1 of many similar rows based on non-numerical priority

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm pulling data from a table that has a number of similar rows that contain different values in the columns I want based on the value of one other column. I want to pull 1 row from each of these groups of similar rows using a priority of certain non-numerical values.

In the following example I want 1 row from each of the field1 values, giving me the row that has "W" in field2 if available. If "W" is not available in field2 then I want the row with "C". If "C" is not in field2 then finally give me the row with "O" in field2.

Example Table:

```
field1  field2  field3  field4
1       O       1/1/13
1       W       1/1/13  5/2/13
2       C       1/1/13
2       O    
3       W               2/1/14
3       C       9/3/13  1/5/14
4       C               11/5/13
4       O       1/2/12
4       W       1/2/12  5/7/14
5       O
```

Desired results:

```
field1  field2  field3  field4
1       W       1/1/13  5/2/13
2       C       1/1/13
3       W               2/1/14
4       W       1/2/12  5/7/14
5       O
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `row_number()`:

```
select field1, field2, field3, field4
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by field1
                                order by (case when field2 = 'W' then 1
                                               when field2 = 'C' then 2
                                               when field2 = 'O' then 3
                                               else 4
                                         )
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```